# Learning how to use scrollview and autoresizing

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I was learning how to use autoresizing and scroll view also and came up with this solution which works, just your feedback would be welcome on my approach if it is ok how it could be improved etc.

I just created a test view controller whose view looks like this.

[image: Images]

The grey area is a `UIView` called `mainView` and it is subview of view controller's view (and it's longer than view controller's view).

When I changed rotation one would see such thing:

[image]

You can see the calculator does not fit on the screen anymore.
So I decided to have a UIScrollView already from start. Add `mainView` as a subview to it.

Final thing that was remaining, I wanted the frame of the ScrollView to change also when device rotates, so that I could get such effect:

[image]

(you see the scroll views width is same as phones).

This is how I implemented all this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];

    [[self view] addSubview:scrollView];

    [scrollView addSubview:self.mainView];


    [scrollView setContentSize:[mainView bounds].size];

    [scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];

}
```

Any comments and feedback?

Comment: What are your concerns? Have you considered doing all of this in Interface Builder instead of code? Have you considered support both orientations by adjusting the sizes and positions of the controls rather than using a scroll view?

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Hi Marcus, I didn't consider doing it in interface builder as I was doing it for learning purposes, so this code approach is also fine for me. Not that I have concerns, just was curious it it was ok approach. I didn't consider to do it without scrollview as I was not sure how to adjust sizes. etc. (I could try minimizing height of buttons - is it smth you are referring to?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the didRotate methods to position your buttons how you want in the different orientations. There is a good tutorial here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3yb24f8O1Y&list=PL53038489615793F7